# usePreviousEffect typings with tuple type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to create typed version of usePreviousEffect hook but getting some strange behaviour.
Hook:

```ts
export const usePreviousEffect = <TInputs extends unknown[]>(fn: (inp: TInputs) => ReturnType<typeof useEffect>, inputs: TInputs) => {
    const previousInputsRef = useRef([...inputs]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fn(previousInputsRef.current);
        previousInputsRef.current = [...inputs];
    }, inputs);
};
```

Usage:

```ts
usePreviousEffect(
    ([oldDep1,oldDep2]) => {
},[dep1,dep2]);
```

I want oldDep1 to be dep1 type and oldDep2 to be dep2 type. Currently each element is an union type of everything in dep list. Any idea how to type it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for Typescript ≥ 4.0.

You may use [variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) to type arguments of your function.

```ts
export const usePreviousEffect = <
    TInputs extends unknown[]
>(fn: (inp: TInputs) => ReturnType<typeof useEffect>, inputs: TInputs) => {
    const previousInputsRef = useRef(inputs);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fn(previousInputsRef.current);
        previousInputsRef.current = [...inputs];
    }, inputs);
};

usePreviousEffect(([oldDep1,oldDep2]) => {
},[dep1,dep2]);
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXRGJm)

Comment: Awesome stuff!!

Answer (score 1):

First, the upper constraint of `TInputs` should be a `readonly unknown[]`.

```js
export const usePreviousEffect = <TInputs extends readonly unknown[]>(fn: (inp: TInputs) => ReturnType<typeof useEffect>, inputs: TInputs) => {
  const previousInputsRef = useRef([...inputs]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fn(previousInputsRef.current);
    previousInputsRef.current = [...inputs];
  }, inputs);
};
```

Then, add `as const` after the inputs array ([`as const` Doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference)).

```js
usePreviousEffect(
    ([oldDep1,oldDep2]) => {
},[dep1,dep2] as const);
```

The `readonly` is needed since `as const` infer a readonly tuple which is a subtype of readonly array but not normal array.